# What is the main difference between bundle and bundleSFX in jspm?

Tags: javascript, frontend, jspm, web-frontend

I have tried harder and harder to understand the difference between bundle and bundle SFX from the documentation of JSPM and system.js. But I was unable to get the difference. I haven't used jspm till now but I want to use it in my current project.

Another question - If I am importing different modules in a.js and different modules in b.js, where both a.js and b.js are mutually exclusive, can I bundle both of them in a single file c.js using JSPM?

Please help, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

> To create an output distributable script file that can be included
>   entirely on its own independent of SystemJS and jspm, we can use
>   bundle-sfx.
>
> `jspm bundle-sfx app/main.js app.js app.js`
>
> contains a micro-loader
>   implementation (1.4KB gzipped), converts all module formats into ES5
>   (including compiling ES6), and maintaining bindings and circular
>   references as with normal bundles.

Source: http://jspm.io/docs/production-workflows.html